# Make a line/stand in a line

Tags: word-usage, spoken-english

If a teacher asks her students to line up (or form a line), will it be equally natural to express this idea this way:

> Please **make** a line.
>
> Please **stand** in a line.

Is the use of "make/stand" natural or unnatural? And is it common?

Comment: Either seems acceptable to me. You could also use "Please form a line".

Comment: Those are quite acceptable.  "Form a line" is good, as is "Queue up."

Comment: "Everybody get in line" is also good, but a bit informal.  "Get in line" has a bit of an air of rudeness, though.  It is even worse without the "Everybody" before it to spread it out.

Answer (score 2):

Either is acceptable, as is "Form a line", or perhaps "Get in line" (though that is rather direct).

If the purpose of the line is to wait in turn for something you could also use "Queue" as "Make a queue", or "Queue up for (something)"